# How can I save markdown files with the .md file extension in Notepad?

Tags: markdown

I am using git and github with my research students and we document all of our work with markdown formatted files so they will look good in github.

My students do not have strong computer and coding backgrounds so working with git and text files is unfamiliar to them initially and thus I try to minimize the new software etc... that they have to use at first.  When they open `.md` template files on Windows it automatically opens in Notepad (which is good) but when they save their changes with a new file name using `Save As` it seems to only be able to save with a `.txt` file extension.

Is there a way to get Notepad to `Save As` files with anything other than a `.txt` extension?

Comment: Are they doing a `Save As`? Because after Notepad opens the file it saves to the same file, without change the extension. Unless they go `Save As`, which defaults to `.txt`.

Comment: @shinjijai I can look into that, Currently they are using `save as` because they open a template file that they modify and then save under a different name.  Is there no way to get it not to default to `.txt` with `save as`? (I clarified this in the question, thanks)

Comment: When using `Save As`, they can double quotes (ie: `"markdown.md"`) and it'll save it without adding `.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

I tested the following, and it saved a .md file using notepad:

- File -> Save As...
- Where it says "Save as type:" change the dropdown from "*.txt" to "All Files"
- Where it says "File name:" type something which ends with ".md"